# MULE BOX Connector - Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload

Tags: mule, box

I am using `Mule 3.7.3` . Below is the Flow -

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<box:config name="Box" clientId="05zpeboxxfms6fo7805izrxff9dwbc74" clientSecret="LVD5juoF7ookFVn4uN69Pco3NI4EQeE0" doc:name="Box">
    <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8080" remotePort="8080" path="callback"/>
</box:config>
<flow name="boxAuthenticationFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <box:authorize config-ref="Box" doc:name="Box-Authorize" accessTokenId="FgL53vlbdYMaXDMykVzS8z7CKz8QsZ0J"/>
        <box:create-folder config-ref="Box" folderName="test folder" doc:name="Box"/>
</flow>
```

But I am getting below error after i select Authorize. ..

> Message               : Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
>   Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
>   Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>   Payload               : {NullPayload}
>   JavaDoc               :
>
> ---
>
> Exception stack is:
>   1. Connection timed out: connect (java.net.ConnectException)
>     java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl:-2 (null)
>   2. Error found while consuming http resource at https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token (java.lang.RuntimeException)
>     org.mule.security.oauth.util.HttpUtilImpl:93 (null)
>   3. Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
>     org.mule.security.oauth.processor.OAuth2FetchAccessTokenMessageProcessor:95

Tried a lot but no change in behavior need helps please ..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
     <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
  <box:config name="Box" clientId="05zpeboxxfms6fo7805izrxff9dwbc74" clientSecret="LVD5juoF7ookFVn4uN69Pco3NI4EQeE0" doc:name="Box">
        <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8082" remotePort="8082" path="callback" />
    </box:config>
    <objectstore:config name="ObjectStore" objectStore-ref="_defaultInMemoryObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore: Configuration" />
    <flow name="boxAuthenticationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <box:authorize config-ref="Box" doc:name="Box-Authorize"  />
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars._oauthVerifier]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <box:create-folder config-ref="Box" folderName="test folder" doc:name="Box"/>
    </flow>
```

It's an working code. All the best.

http://thirumal-opensource.blogspot.in/2016/05/how-to-get-authentication-from-box.html